# Do I need to include same javascript files across all html pages in my webapplication?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Say I have a web application with root page: index.html .

I include some functionality to index.html by including a JavaScript file say,myJs.js

Now I have one more page afterIndex.html which requires the same myJS.js file for its functionality

And the flow of the web application is always index.html->afterIndex.html

Do I need to include myJs.js in both the HTML pages?

As someone new to this ,it seems like I am doing some basic mistake here..

Comment: are you using apache tiles ?

Comment: no ,I am not using any frame work

Comment: From what you describe the short answer is yes, you have to include it again in the afterIndex.html.